# Get data from table with multiple criteria Excel

Tags: excel, search, copy, copy-paste, paste

So i have information stored in a table. The columns are the date und rows are the Part. So i have another workbook open with different dates and parts but the table looks completely differnt with some addition rows in between. So i cant just copy&paste the data. I need a vba code to search for the correct entry and copy paste each single value. Similar to a index match function but in vba. 
Could you give me some help how to start this?

Comment: You have to show some example of your Data

Comment: Why VBA? What have you tried? You can do `Index/Match` with multiple criteria, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

So that would be my initial table:(Information 2)

```
           Date 1  Date 2  Date 3
  Part A    122    134      1212
  Part B    453     3       4536
  Part C    35      23      3
```

I need to copy that information into another table with different outline:

```
                       Part A     Part B    Part C
             Info 1
    Date1    Info 2    122         453
             Info 3
             Info 1
   Date 2    Info 2    134         3
             Info 3
             Info 1
   Date 3    Info 2    1212       4536
             Info 3
```

How could i copy& paste the information into the new table?
How could i do that with index &match funtion?